# Drupal 6 sql injection

Tags: sql, security, drupal, code-injection, exploit

Is Drupal 6.x is vulnerable to SQL injection Attack AKA Drupalgeddon?

If yes, what are vulnerable forms, directory or anything?

Comment: Shouldn't this be covered in the release notes of Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was. It received a patch (long-term support).

> The vulnerability has been patched with the release of Drupal 7.58,
>   8.5.1, 8.3.9 and 8.4.6. While Drupal 6 has reached end of life and it’s not supported since February 2016, a fix has still been developed
>   due to the severity of the flaw and the high risk of exploitation.
>   https://www.securityweek.com/drupalgeddon-critical-flaw-exposes-million-drupal-websites-attacks

Here is the patch for version 6: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/d6lts/tree/common/core/SA-CORE-2018-002.patch or the full release: https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/releases/tag/6.44 that contains commits for SA-CORE-2018-001,002,004

Comment: Yeah thanks man, but I want to know how a hacker can exploit it?